# How can I modify an object from a function?

Tags: c++

I want to add coins earned when the user uses the work function to an object called user from a class called Player .

```
int Player::addCoins(int coinAmount) {
    coins += coinAmount;
}


int DoWork()
{
    const int MAX_NUMBER = 5000;
    int randomNumber;
    srand(time(0));
    randomNumber = (rand () % MAX_NUMBER);
    cout << "You went to work and earned: $" << randomNumber << endl;
    user.addCoins(randomNumber); // user not in scope.
    return randomNumber;
}
```

I don't want to make the user object inside the DoWork function as other functions will also add 'coins' and other things to the object. However, if I do not then I will get an error as it isn't in scope.

So, how can I have lots of different functions add 'coins' to the object when the object is in main?

What if the user object had to be inside a function?

I don't to do `user.addCoins(randomNumber);` in the main method because then I would have to do it everytime the user calls it.

Yes, I am new to C++ and programming in general.

Comment: Make your function take in `user` as a parameter.

Comment: your function should look something like this : `int DoWork(Player& user)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a reference to `user` to the function:

```
int DoWork(Player& user)
{
    const int MAX_NUMBER = 5000;
    int randomNumber;
    srand(time(0));
    randomNumber = (rand () % MAX_NUMBER);
    cout << "You went to work and earned: $" << randomNumber << endl;
    user.addCoins(randomNumber); // calls method on the parameter
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Now your function can work on any `Player` not just a single one called `user`.